# Waiting time between two given Times

Tags: java, time, sleep

I propose a method to stop a program for a time given by the difference between two times.

```
Time end = ...
Time begin =....
if (end.getHours() == begin.getHours()) {
    Thread.sleep((end.getMinutes()-begin.getMinutes())*60000);
} else {
    Thread.sleep(((60-begin.getMinutes())+ (end.getMinutes())+(end.getHours()-begin.getHours())*60)*60000);
}
```

What do you think about? Is there an easier way?

Comment: The problem you will run into is that there is no context to the time values.  What happens if the start time is before midnight, but the end time is after midnight?

Comment: begin is always at least <=end, that's why i named this way;
and both belongs to the same day that's why are Time object and not Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do you think about? Is there an easier way?

Since I assume you are talking about `java.sql.Time` which extends `java.util.Date`, I'd use the `getTime()` method to get the time in millis:

```
Thread.sleep(end.getTime() - begin.getTime());
```

No conversions necessary.  Any solution that uses the deprecated `getHours()` or `getMinutes()` methods is going to be buggy around daylight savings time transitions because the number of hours will jump around.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems quite complicated, and therefore probably wrong.

Since it looks like homework, I'll give you just a hint. Try to convert the times in a simpler unit of measure first, and then take the difference of that.

Eg. convert both times in the number of minutes since the beginning of the day, then subtract those:

- 7.30 -> 450
- 8.10 -> 490
- Difference: 490-450 = 40 mins

Comment: This assumes that the time is within a single day.  What happens if the start time is before midnight and the end time is after midnight (the next day)? :P

Comment: Best solution so far!

Comment: Methods that deal with minutes/hours/etc. are deprecated and should not be used because they would not work around daylight savings, etc..  See my answer.

Comment: I assumed `Time` was a custom class, not using deprecated methods of `java.sql` classes :) I quite agree @Gray solution is the right one, since where are talking about `java.sql.Time`.

Answer (score 0):

In the else section of your code, since you have

> (60-begin.getMinutes())

you would have to subtract 60 minutes from the total, so the code wouldn't work like this. Also , you need another pair of parentheses. Instead, try this:

```
else{
    Thread.sleep(((end.getMinutes()-begin.getMinutes())+(end.getHours()-begin.getHours())*60)*6000);
}
```